# How to have bootstrap popover styled in more than one way?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using Boostrap to code a single page website.
In a graph I have some popvers on mouse hover, and that works fine.
The problem is when I try to have more than a style for popovers: i.e. Some popovers must be yellow, others must be blue etc.
I tried adding a new style in css and substitute it in html (i.e.: "popover2"), or using inline css, but the popover style is associated with the popover script and I cannot see any changes.
The "problem" I think starts from here:

```
$.fn.popover = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('popover')
        , options = typeof option == 'object' && option
      if (!data) $this.data('popover', (data = new Popover(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  $.fn.popover.Constructor = Popover

  $.fn.popover.defaults = $.extend({} , $.fn.tooltip.defaults, {
    placement: 'right'
  , trigger: 'click'
  , content: ''
  , template: '<div class="popover"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
  })

}(window.jQuery);
```

I've even tried duplicanting the .js and using popover2 as a new object... no way...
Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in plain HTML/CSS quite easily. The popover appear just after the link/button which means you can target it with the `+` selector in CSS. Here something you can try :

The HTML :

```
<a rel="popover" data-color="yellow" data-etc="...">My popover</a>
```

The CSS :

```
[rel=popover][data-color=yellow] + .popover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

EDIT : And it works, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/4cfHL/).

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work:
I've HTML 
data-content='
                    <div>
                      <div class="arrow"></div>
                      <div class="popover-inner" >
                        <div class="popover-content">
                          <ul >
                            <li >...</li>
                            ...
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ' href="#">My popover</a>

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com exemple of your code ? I just copied the HTML used in the bootstrap for this example.

Comment: here it is [link](http://jsfiddle.net/f_costaldi/tWqUr/11/) --- sorry I'm not really used to it

Comment: Can you please make the popover works in your fiddle ? I can't really help you without it working.

Comment: +1 Excellent, I was trying to add a class to the $tip object of the popover but this is much cleaner

Comment: The answer is 1.5 years old, it was for an older version of Bootstrap.